# Can I set a trigger to fire when a function is executed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a trigger in Spreadsheet App, but I didn't figure out how to set a trigger to fire when a function is executed, even if it was executed from a `onEdit(e)` event. For an instance, I want to check if a content was changed when I run a function.

I observed that when something is changed or edited by a custom function in spreadsheet it does not trigger the `onEdit()` / `onChange()` functions. Is there  any way to do this, or better, to set a trigger when a function is executed, even if in background?

Comment: For your sheet is content only changed via script or can users edit as well?  If it is only via script you may be able to use .getDataRange() to compare before and after as a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, writing something on sheet via appscript function cannot trigger onEdit/onChange trigger available in appscript. Also, even when you copy paste the data in spreadsheet, it will not trigger the onEdit trigger.

In such case, Like @Zaq said in his answer, write that function's or trigger's code in your basic function itself.

Alternatively, you can create a new sheet in your spreadsheet with only one cell and whenever your function runs, write 'called' or something in it. And check in your trigger function continuously (i.e. 1 min trigger) whether the value is 'called' or not. If yes, run your trigger and reset the value else do nothing.

Comment: Yes, i tought about this but it would be more professional if had a function like onClick()...haha

Anyway, thanks (:

Comment: If it works, and its optimal and perfect, then it is professional ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no trigger that fires when an Apps Script function runs.

If you want something to happen when a certain function runs, you can do it by including a call such as `doSomething()` in the body of that function.

Comment: I've done it now. I've imbued my functions with other to check if anything was changed. Thanks (: